# Fill in the missing number style question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, puzzle

This nice question from a math competition doesn't seem to make any sense.

> What number should replace the question mark?
>   $$\begin{matrix} 22 & (4) & 82 \\ 73 & (3) & 97 \\ 93 & (?) & 99 \end{matrix}$$

Comment: It is a pattern-recognition question, *therefore* it is made with the purpose of seemingly (and, in my opinion, effectively) make little, if any, sense.

Comment: I have nothing to loose if i say it is $2$.

Comment: Try puzzling.SE

Comment: In particular, https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33263/correct-way-to-add-22-to-4-to-get-82 may be relevant.

Comment: 3 votes to close the question?? **slow clap**

Comment: These kind of questions are both primarily opinion based and not really math.

Comment: It attracts close votes because there is no objectively true answer, or even objectively wrong answer. As far as this site is concerned, it's a glorified version of the problem "What number am I thinking of now?" Puzzling.SE is different.

Answer (score 2):

$22\equiv 82\mod 4$

$73\equiv 97\mod 3$

$93\equiv 99\mod 6$

So you could fill in ?=6. But without any context you could probably justify anything.

Answer (score 2):

I can't really verify if this is the correct pattern, but it's definitely *a* pattern here.  In the first number in each row, swap the two digits.  Then multiply the swapped first digit by the number in the parentheses to get the first digit in the last number in each row.

---

$$ 22 \quad (4) \quad 82 $$

Swap the $2$ and $2$ (so nothing changes, really..) and multiply the first $2$ by $(4)$ to get $8$.  Replace first digit with $8$ and you have $82$.

---

$$ 73 \quad (3) \quad 97 $$

Swap the $7$ and $3$ and multiply the $3$ by $(3)$ to get $9$.  Replace first digit with $9$ and you have $97$.

---

$$ 93 \quad (?) \quad 99 $$

Swap the $9$ and $3$ and multiply the $3$ by $(?)$ to get $9$.  Replace first digit with $9$ and you have $99$.  Thus the $(?)$ must be $(3)$.

---

But as the (currently only) other answer says, without context you can probably justify anything.

Comment: The fact that we have two different but equally valid answer ATM is why I hate these pattern recognition questions on intelligence tests.  Who is to say that the pattern the test taker sees is the one that the test maker intended?  Edit: three answers now.

Comment: The parenthesis seem to hint that the middle numbers are they key to combining the side numbers. And indeed as the outer digits are identical, your solution seems quite likely.

Comment: @Bye_World: in such puzzles, one recognizes a good solution to its compacity, i.e. the small number of operations to be performed (i.e. the description length). It is often the case that there is a solution that stands out, but it is rewarding to fiind another, equally compact. Typical solutions are often small degree polynomials or arithmetico-geometric progressions, and its is pleasing to see new, so-far-unthought-of tricks. Another numerical sequence: o t t f f s s e...

Comment: @Bye_World, I feel the same way, although I like to think that those tests are designed well enough so that only one of the options (they're usually multiple choice) makes sense.  Probably not always the case but on the plus side, IIRC, the "real" IQ tests aren't about pattern matching in the same sense as this question.

Answer (score 0):

The following procedure is probably the right one:

1. Take the first number, split it to digits $73 \rightarrow (7,3)$
2. swap the order of the digits $(7,3)\rightarrow(3,7)$
3. multiply the (now) first digit by the number in the ()'s: $(3,7) \rightarrow (3\times(3),7)$
4. evaluate the numbers $(3\times 3,7)\rightarrow (9,7)$
5. Combine the digits again to single number: $(9,7) \rightarrow 97$

Now the trick for the last one is to figure out what goes to the ()'s, so we get
$$ 93 \rightarrow (9,3)$$
$$ (9,3)\rightarrow (3,9)$$
$$ (3,9)\rightarrow (3 \times(x),9)$$
Now at this point, we might start from the end, going backwards(from step5):
$$ 99 \rightarrow (9,9) $$
$$ (9,9) \rightarrow (3 \times(x),9) $$
$$ 9 = 3 \times(x)$$
$$ x=3 $$

Result: question mark is replaced by "$3$".

Comment: You've just repeated tilper's answer.

Comment: yup, guess I'm slow :-)